# How can I find ROS packages on GitHub?

Tags: ros, github

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I find ROS packages on GitHub? I thought about e.g. using the GitHub search field with something like `<package> filename:package extension:xml` to search for `package.xml` files which contain `<package>` ([GitHub syntax for searching code](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/)). But I did not come up with a suitable serach pattern so far.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273228/how-can-i-find-ros-packages-on-github?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2017-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure how useful it is (ie: I get way too many results), but if I search with `ros filetype:xml site:github.com` I only get links to `package.xml` files, which would seem to belong to ROS pkgs.

Note that `package.xml` files are also used by some other (OSS) projects.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-17**:
Btw: seeing this - and your other questions: is there some specific context you are asking all these questions from/in? Automated testing (roswtf, fuzzing, etc) + automated discovery of packages seems to start to point in a certain direction ..

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-10-17**:
Yes, I try to find information about automated testing in ROS. Many lower level testing topics are generic and independent of the company I am working for. As everyone depends on other peoples packages (up to the ROS node level I guess) I am planning to share generic information...

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-10-17**:
... about how to improve reliability (w.r.t. that the package does what it is meant for from a functional validation and verification point of view) of ROS packages in a [GitBook](https://github.com/fkromer/building-reliability-into-ros-package). (wiki.ros.org turned out to be not suitable for me.)

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2017-10-17**:
Searching on google for `ros filetype:xml site:github.com` is quite ok.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-17**:
And just leaving this here: [ROS Index](http://rosindex.github.io).